# how to convert a json "looking" file into a list of records using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a file in S3 which has below content (no new lines).

```
{"name":"A","phone":{"mobile":"","landline":""},...otherkeys}{"name":"B",...otherkeys}{"name":"C","phone":{"mobile":"","":""},...otherkeys}{"name":"D",...otherkeys}
```

The file can have 1 or n number of such records one after the other.
The end goal is to be able to iterate through these individual records and perform some operation.
For that I think the best way would be to convert these into a list and then iterate through them.

How should I go about in achieving this ?

I tried something like below but it's not giving me expected result.

```
const d = raw.split('}{');
// try to iterate over d
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a string of JSON objects that may have nested objects within them, the solution I can think of will have to be an involved process such as a loop.

The next loop parses through all the character in the string, making some efficient steps like only parsing through important characters (`"`, `{` and `}`).

We'll keep track of the depth of our location in relation to the root object with `bracketDelta`. Once this reaches 0 it means that every `{` has it's corresponding `}`.

We also keep track of wether or not we are in a string or not. So that we can skip the evaluation of a bracket match.

I've commented the code thoroughly, let me know if this helps:

```js
const raw = `{"name":"A","phone":{"mobile":"1{2}}}3","landline":124}}{"name":"B"}{"name":"C","phone":{"mobile":"a","key":"b"}}{"name":"D"}`;

// array of root json objects, as strings
const parentObjects: string[] = [];
// current root object being built
let currentObject = "";
// delta of open and close brackets, used to determine when a root object is complete
let bracketDelta = 0;
// whether the current character is inside a string
let isInQuote = false;

for (let i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
  const char = raw[i];
  // if the character is a quote, toggle the isInQuote flag
  if (char === '"') {
    isInQuote = !isInQuote;
  }
  // if the character is an open bracket and we are not in a string
  if (char === "{" && !isInQuote) {
    bracketDelta++;
  }
  // if the character is a close bracket and we are not in a string
  if (char === "}" && !isInQuote) {
    bracketDelta--;
  }

  currentObject += char;

  // if the bracket delta is 0, we have a complete root object
  // because every open bracket has a corresponding close bracket
  if (bracketDelta === 0) {
    parentObjects.push(currentObject);
    currentObject = "";
    // skip searching for the next open or close bracket
    // because we know the next character is a an open bracket
    // or the end of the string
    continue;
  }

  // in order to make this loop more efficient, we can skip ahead to the next
  // open or close bracket as well as the next quote
  const nextOpenIndex = raw.indexOf("{", i + 1);
  const nextCloseIndex = raw.indexOf("}", i + 1);
  const nextQuoteIndex = raw.indexOf('"', i + 1);
  let nextIndex = raw.length;
  if (nextOpenIndex !== -1) nextIndex = nextOpenIndex;
  if (nextCloseIndex !== -1) nextIndex = Math.min(nextIndex, nextCloseIndex);
  if (nextQuoteIndex !== -1) nextIndex = Math.min(nextIndex, nextQuoteIndex);

  // add whatever is between the current and the next match to the current object
  currentObject += raw.slice(i + 1, nextIndex);
  // set the index to right before the next match
  // this is because the for loop will increment the index by 1
  i = nextIndex - 1;
}

// parse each item in the array
const parsed = parentObjects.map((x) => JSON.parse(x));

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I think this approach will cause issues when there are nested dict inside each element. Updated the example.

Comment: @Naxi I've updated my answer as well. It should work with your example now.

Answer (score 0):

Found below one-liner which worked perfectly for my use case.

```
const input = '{"name":"paul", "contact":{"mobile":1234, "cell":890}}{"name":"soham"}{"name":"soham","gender":"male"}{"hello":"hi", "contact":{"mobile":1234, "cell":890}}';

const object = JSON.parse(`[${input.replace(/}{/g, '},{')}]`);
```